# Deleting Label that was created in Models

Tags: python, html, django, django-crispy-forms

[image]Hello I have a project where I have a form to post something, but when I am rendering it I become an ugly label. I was wondering if it is possible to delete it.
Thanks...

I also posted a picture where you can see what I want to delete

I searched a lot and found that I can rename the label or set the auto_id to false but they didnt helped maybe I made it wrong

views.py

```
class PostList(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    form=PostForm
    model = PostModel
    fields=['post']
    success_url="/home"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author=self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

models.py

```
class PostModel(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.post)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post
```

forms.py

```
from .models import PostModel
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=PostModel
        fields=['post','author']
        unlabelled_fields=('post')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True
        for field in PostForm.Meta.unlabelled_fields:
            self.fields[field].label = False
```

home.html

```
[![{% extends "base.html" %}
{%block content%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-3 left mx-auto">
            {% for posts in postmodel_list %}
            <div class="card mb-4 block">
                <a class="overlay" href="{% url 'post_detail' posts.slug  %}"style="text-decoration:none"> </a>
                <div class="card-body inner">
                  <p style="text-align:right;float:right;margin-top:10px;" class="card-text text-muted h6"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="https://google.com">@{{ posts.author }}</a> </p>
                  <h2 class="card-title">{{ posts.post }}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>

</div>


<div class="col-md-4 float-right ">
  <button style= "position: fixed; bottom:50px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Add New Post</button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Post</h5>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form|crispy }}
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
       </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>




<style>
.card{
  box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
}
</style>

{%endblock content%}][1]][1]
```

Comment: in form set label to empty string.